# rbind two different data frames that have different column names

Tags: r, rbind

I want to rbind two different data frames that have different column names

DF1 has 4 columns

| Year | Month | Prec_CAN_45 | Prec_CAN_85 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | Jan | 0.5 | 0.65 |
| 2100 | Jan | 0.6 | 0.75 |

DF2 has 3 columns

| Year | Month | Prec_CAN_45 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1998 | Jan | 0.3 |
| 2014 | Jan | 0.4 |

I want to create DF3 that has DF2 pasted above the DF1 rows in both columns (c3, c4)

| Year | Month | Prec_CAN_45 | Prec_CAN_85 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1998 | Jan | 0.3 | 0.3 |
| 2014 | Jan | 0.4 | 0.4 |
| 2015 | Jan | 0.5 | 0.65 |
| 2100 | Jan | 0.6 | 0.75 |

Comment: Would it not make more sense, from a data consistency point of view, to have blank values for `Prec_CAN_85`, years 1998 and 2014? Your example would seem to assign incorrect values to `Prec_CAN_85`, unless I misunderstand it.

Comment: I want to create a time series for both Prec_CAN_45 and Prec_CAN_85. These values refer to future values. while from 1998-2014 are historical values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to simply duplicate the column `Prec_CAN_45` in `df2` and rename it to `Prec_CAN_85`. Then you can use `rbind` to combine the two data tables.

Here's an easy `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df2 %>% dplyr::mutate(Prec_CAN_85 = Prec_CAN_45)

df3 <- rbind(df2, df1)

df3
#>    Year Month Prec_CAN_45 Prec_CAN_85
#>   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1  1998 Jan           0.3        0.3 
#> 2  2014 Jan           0.4        0.4 
#> 3  2015 Jan           0.5        0.65
#> 4  2100 Jan           0.6        0.75
```

Similarly, a base `R` solution might look like:

```
df2$Prec_CAN_85 <- df2$Prec_CAN_45

df3 <- rbind(df2, df1)

df3
#>    Year Month Prec_CAN_45 Prec_CAN_85
#>   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1  1998 Jan           0.3        0.3 
#> 2  2014 Jan           0.4        0.4 
#> 3  2015 Jan           0.5        0.65
#> 4  2100 Jan           0.6        0.75
```

Comment: You could also do it in-line without having to change DF2 first, e.g.: `DF2 %>% mutate(Prec_CAN_85 = Prec_CAN_45) %>% bind_rows(DF1)` or `rbind(DF1, cbind(DF2, Prec_CAN_85=DF2$Prec_CAN_45))`